# Confusion regarding properties of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I just had some confusion about linearity of inner product.

In my course notes, it's said that inner product is linear in first slot i.e.

$\langle u+w,v\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle + \langle w,v\rangle$ and $\langle au,v\rangle = a\langle u,v\rangle$

But when I searched for logical explanations, I stumbled upon a video which said that inner product is linear in second argument i.e.

$\langle u,v+w\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle + \langle u,w\rangle$ and $\langle u,\lambda v\rangle = \lambda \langle u,v\rangle$

But neither of the sources said about the other slot/argument.

So, in which slot/argument is inner product actually linear?

Comment: If you work over $\mathbb{R}$, it doesn't matter, these are equivalent. If you work over $\mathbb{C}$, it's a matter of definition. Most books define inner product to be linear in the first variable. But my linear algebra professor defined it to be linear in the second variable. So it depends. Most important thing is to know what definition you are using, and keep working with it.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks. I just studied inner product today so I was totally confused

Comment: By the way, please use MathJax when you write here. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Further to @Mark's comment, the second argument is linear when physicists do quantum mechanics, but mathematicians typically make the first argument linear. Could you link to the video you saw? I wonder if it's about quantum mechanics.